# Captioning images within a framed environment?

Tags: captions, framed

I have an image within a framed environment and would like to caption it. Using the figure environment crashes the compiler

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={170mm,257mm}, left=20mm, top=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{framed}
    Lots and lots of text
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics{Image.JPG}
        \caption{Caption}
        \label{fig:my_label}
    \end{figure}
    Lots more text
\end{framed}
\end{document}
```

I have found way to still include the image within my frame

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={170mm,257mm}, left=20mm, top=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{framed}
    Lots and lots of text
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics{Image.JPG}
    \end{center}
    Lots more text
\end{framed}
\end{document}
```

However, this method does not allow me to caption or label the image. How do I caption an image that is positioned within a framed environment.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you tried `\captionof` from package `caption`?

Comment: I hadn't. It solved my problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm putting this in an answer so that it can be more easily seen by future visitors.

As Mensch commented, the `\captionof` command allows you to create a caption outside of a float environment. The following code achieves what I wanted

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={170mm,257mm}, left=20mm, top=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{framed}
    Lots and lots of text
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics{example-image-a}
        \captionof{figure}{Caption}
    \end{center}
    Lots more text
\end{framed}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are right, it was supposed to import caption as well

Comment: You can accept your answer too :-)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it, I accepted my answer